# Why does ICS not come with some icons for Holo Light?

Tags: android

I'm trying to use ic_menu_refresh in my project. However, I need it for the Holo Light theme, which I can't find in the Android SDK (android-15/data/res/drawable-hdpi). It's there for Holo Dark, though.

I also found it in the Gmail APK, so I could take it from there...

But why does Android 4.0 only come with **some** of the icons for both themes? (Or am I looking in the wrong place?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't appear that they come in the SDK /data/res/drawable-[SIZE], but you can get some of them from this page: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html (or direct link: [REDACTED - see below])

That has both holo and holo light icons in that zip.

Comment: Edited out of reply. They moved the downloads to a different page: http://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html titled "Action Bar Icon Pack"

Answer (score 4):

You are right. And while you can download the zip file of all standard icons from the android design page (as @Troy McCabe said), this zip file **does not include xxhdpi versions**. The best way, which will also give you the xxhdpi version of standard icons in both Holo Light and Dark as well as custom colors, is to:

Go to [Android asset studio](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html) and select [Action bar and tab icons](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/icons-actionbar.html#source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=ic_action_example&theme=light&color=33b5e5,60). In that page, select **CLIPART** as the Source and pick whichever icon that you want. You can select Holo Light, Dark, or any custom color for the icons.

Answer (score 2):

The best place for standard icons is [Android Asset Studio](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure? I just searched my SDK directory and found a bunch of *holo_light*png files.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. Some icons have Holo Light versions, but some (like ic_menu_refresh) only have Holo Dark versions, with no theme name in the file name.